# Google Cloud Functions Deployment Failure - Unexplained

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-functions

We're trying to deploy our Google Cloud Functions, but keep getting this error. We get the same error when trying to trigger our functions.

Everything worked fine until today, with no code changes.

**Error message**:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=13, message=Failure in the execution environment
```

**Steps Taken**:

- Delete all functions
- Redeploy all functions (gcloud SDK)

AFAICT, these are Kubernetes errors, which appears to be a GCF implementation detail leaking through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was a bug in GCF.

Contacted support team for resolution. There was an outage at the same time (thanks @Frank van Puffelen), but it was unrelated.

Comment: Joseph, can I ask you how did you manage to contact the support team? I'm currently experiencing a very similiar issue.

Comment: @jdscosta91 contacting the GCF support time required purchasing a paid support plan on GCP.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Cloud Functions deployments on Firebase just now. See the [issue status page](https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Functions/17012) for details.

In general, the [Firebase status dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/) is a great place to see if there are any known issues. If there aren't, it doesn't hurt to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) either.

Comment: Thanks, though we don't use FB. However, is a possible GCF outage, as it underpins FB CF.

Comment: Good point, I somehow immediate read it as Firebase. :-)   From what I can see the issue applies to GCF too btw. But that also means that it should've been resolved.